# Controlling fans and undervolting in Acer Nitro 5 with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, gtk, acer, debian, fancontrol

I installed Ubuntu on my **Acer Nitro 5 || 8GB DDR4 || 1TB NVME SSD || i5-9300H || 4GB GTX 1650** laptop, replacing Windows.

Switching to Linux I think there are many features that I am unable to use like *controlling fans and undervolting* as in Windows; so is there any way by which I can get access to such features?

[image: Acer Nitro 5]

Comment: Using NBFC will allow you to control your fans. However, you will have to build the nbfc package yourself on Ubuntu, which can be difficult depending on how used to the Linux terminal you are. https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/ Undervolting is even simpler than it is on Windows. It is only as hard as copy pasting half a dozen commands in series. For your CPU, follow this guide:
https://cryptosingh1337.medium.com/how-to-under-volt-intel-i-series-cpu-in-ubuntu-abc9283f4760

Comment: Thanks, @Dante! it's what I was seeking for.

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrased and abridged, from [How to undervolt Intel i-series CPU in Linux](https://cryptosingh1337.medium.com/how-to-under-volt-intel-i-series-cpu-in-ubuntu-abc9283f4760):

1. Install pip

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-pip
   ```

   Check with

   ```
   pip3 --version
   ```

   Expected output

   ```
   pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
   ```
2. Install undervolt package

   ```
   sudo pip3 install undervolt
   ```

   Check with

   ```
   pip3 show undervolt
   ```

   Expected output

   ```
   Name: undervolt
   Version: 0.3.0
   Summary: Undervolt Intel CPUs under Linux
   Home-page: http://github.com/georgewhewell/undervolt
   Author: George Whewell
   Author-email: georgerw@gmail.com
   License: GPL
   Location: /home/saransh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
   Requires: 
   Required-by:
   ```
3. Add Python installed package path to `PATH` environment variable

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/environment
   ```

   Append `:home/<user>/.local/bin` to `PATH`

   Source new enviroment

   ```
   source /etc/environment
   ```

   Check with

   ```
   echo $PATH
   ```

   Expected output

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/saransh/.local/bin"
   ```

   Check with

   ```
   sudo undervolt --read
   ```

   Expected output

   ```
   temperature target: -5 (95C)
   core: -128.91 mV
   gpu: 0.0 mV
   cache: -128.91 mV
   uncore: 0.0 mV
   analogio: 0.0 mV
   powerlimit: 60.0W (short: 0.00244140625s - disabled) / 45.0W (long: 28.0s - enabled)
   ```
4. Create service to run upon boot

   ```
   cd /etc/systemd/system/
   sudo nano undervolt.service
   ```

   Paste in

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=undervolt
   After=suspend.target
   After=hibernate.target
   After=hybrid-sleep.target

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/undervolt -v --core -150 --cache -150 --gpu -100

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   WantedBy=suspend.target
   WantedBy=hibernate.target
   WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
   ```

   ***NOTE: change `--core` and `--cache` arguments according to your CPU. Do some research about your CPU stable offset voltage, else your system will shutdown and reset to default offset voltage, i.e. 0.0 mV, or may cause damage to your system!!!***

   Check with

   ```
   systemctl start undervolt.service
   systemctl enable undervolt.service
   ```

   **Stress test CPU to find the stable offset voltage**

   Install stress package to Stress test the CPU

   ```
   sudo apt install stress
   ```

   Run stress test

   ```
   stress -c <CPU cores>
   ```

   i.e.

   ```
   stress -c 8
   ```
5. Stress test (again) and check CPU temperature

   Install i7z package to monitor the CPU temperature

   ```
   sudo apt install i7z
   ```

   Run monitor in super user session

   ```
   sudo su
   i7z
   ```

   Expected output

   [image: i7z screenshot]

   *Re-run stress test*.

   If CPU temperature goes above 80 °C, then continue the steps below, else you have finished.
6. Disable Turbo boost

   Create start up script

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/local/sbin/no-turbo.sh
   ```

   Paste

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -
   cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate
   echo 1 > no_turbo
   ```

   Create a unit file to run the script on Startup

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/no-turbo.service
   ```

   Paste

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description="Disable Turbo boost"
   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/no-turbo.sh
   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   Check with

   ```
   systemctl start no-turbo.service
   systemctl enable no-turbo.service
   ```

   Turbo boost should now be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Acer Nitro-AN515-55.

Use [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc).

Maybe you can't find a config file for your model of Nitro 5 but it's not important. You can choose another model like "Acer Predator G3-572". It worked for me!

See [Fan Speed Control on Manjaro Linux With Nbfc](https://www.rockyourcode.com/fan-speed-control-on-manjaro-linux-with-nbfc/) for Arch users (but also useful for Ubuntu):

> 1. Install `nbfc` or `nbfc-git`
>
>    ```
>    yay -S nbfc
>    ```
> 2. Enable and Configure nbfc
>
>    Delete conflicting files
>
>    ```
>    sudo mv /opt/nbfc/Plugins/StagWare.Plugins.ECSysLinux.dll /opt/nbfc/Plugins/StagWare.Plugins.ECSysLinux.dll.old
>    ```
>
>    Start tool
>
>    ```
>    sudo systemctl enable nbfc --now
>    ```
>
>    Find recommended configuration:
>
>    ```
>    nbfc config -r
>    ```
>
>    There is no exact match fo the Acer Nitro 5, so use this instead:
>
>    ```
>    nbfc config --apply "Acer Predator G3-572"
>    ```
> 3. Fish functions
>
>    To set the first fan (0) and second fan (1) to automatic mode
>    (`-a`)
>
>    ```
>    function fanauto
>        nbfc set -f 0 -a
>        nbfc set -f 1 -a
>    end
>    ```
>
>    To power up the fans to full speed (`-s 100`)
>
>    ```
>    function fanfull
>        nbfc set -f 0 -s 100
>        nbfc set -f 1 -s 100
>    end
>    ```
>
>    Remember to run `funcsave fanauto` and `funcsave fanfull`!